# reading a binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

Is it necessary to use reinterpret_cast< char*> when reading from a binary file. Since I found that a explicit typecast worked as well e.g. (char*), sizeof(int).

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you are reading from the file? Show us some code.

Comment: Dunno if it is necessary to post the code. But I can tell you the flow: I open the file with the parameter ios::binary, then I use the istream& read ( char* s, streamsize n ); to read it into a int, or double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both reinterpret_cast and the C-style explicit cast do exactly the same thing in your context. I prefer reinterpret_cast as it makes the nastiness more explicit when reading the code.

Comment: so there are some cases that you have to use reinterpret_cast? I haven't tried reading a binary file containing struct. But will that do any difference if I use c-style explicit cast instead of reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Old-style cast may correspond to static_cast, reinterpret_cast or const_cast, or even a combination of them - so it is slightly stronger than even reinterpret_cast but in general they are very similair